# Asp.net Webforms add static content to all screens

Tags: asp.net, webforms

We have a Webforms application, in which no master page was used. There are about 50-60 screens.

Now we have the requirement to add static content to each of the screens as a footer. Is there a way to achieve it programmatically, without modifying each of the screens?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do these screens share a base page in common?

Comment: Unfortunately they don't.

Comment: Is it possible to do so? You could inject a user control to every page with minimum effort if they have shared a base page.

Comment: Given that it's static text, could you use an http module to modify the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to create a Class in the assembly of the project and use that on every page. You still need to edit all pages once to add one line of code, but after that you can maintain it in a single location for the entire project.

In a class file somewhere in the project.

```
public static string pageFooter()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("<br><center><strong>");
    sb.Append("This is the footer.");
    sb.Append("</strong></center>");

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

And then put this on every aspx page.

```
<%= WebApplication1.pageFooter() %>
```

Better still would be to start using a Master page...

Answer (score 2):

I think you should start working on it, I am not sure if you can do that. Two possible way out could be.

1. create a new page with iFrame show each page on iFrame and keep footer same. This approach has a disadvantage that your Address Bar will show only one URL.
2. See if you can use http Handler to ready HTML from each page created & recreate the new page with footer pretended to it.

Comment: I believe this is an over-designed solution for the problem. This is a web application anyway, not a HTML web site.